# Period in title attribute in series of elements does not properly display jQueryUI tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

## Problem

I have a series of tooltips being created by jQuery UI. For the purposes of testing, I have several divs with `title=Lorem ipsum ...` but when the title attribute of last element in this series contains a period, it does not hide that last div and instead displays the title at the bottom of the page, which contains the tooltip.

- Using jQuery UI version 1.12.1

### index.html

```
            <div class="compare__score">
                <p class="score__title">Student-teacher ratio <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquam gravida molestie. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla facilisi. Cras tempor nisi ac ligula molestie commodo. Sed varius magna at justo rutrum, et faucibus sapien cursus" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                {% if district2.stud_teacher_ratio %}
                    <p class="score__number is-last">{{ district2.stud_teacher_ratio}}</p>
                {% else %}
                    <p class="score__number is-last">-</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
```

Comment: Show your Javascript code.

Comment: You probably need to escape the `.` in a selector.